# Can you create a code in array form with this?

Tags: java, arrays, computer-science

Write a Java program that keeps a number from the user and generates an integer between 1
and 7 and displays the name of the weekday.

Comment: what is the relationship between the number from user and generated integer?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Strint array with all weekdays (`{"Sunday", "Monday"...}`) and than get the name by index like this:

```
int day = 2;
System.out.println(weekdays[day - 1]);//output Monday
```